# How can I enable my code to have an actionListener for clicking of a button to retrieve data inputed to a GUI on multiple parts of the code?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, actionevent

I want to perform a computation in my code from netbeans, and the computed data is retrieved from a GUI which has an onButtonClick() action event and listener. I want to be able to access this data repeatedly at constant intervals to aid in the computation. My problem is that my code only allows the computation to be performed once and after that my solution returns a false answer as the variables inputted to the GUI become zeros.

How do I code such that I can constantly access these GUI inputted numbers at fixed time intervals without having to input them over and over?

Comment: Usually you access data on some event. Often when entering data into forms, that event will be a button click, which uses an ActionListener (or AbstractAction). It sounds like you want the event to be a slice of time (which does seem a bit odd to me -- what if the slice occurs right as the user is entering or changing information?) then you could use a Swing Timer, which incidentally also uses an ActionListener.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your GUI is too closely tied to your business logic.

You have many options, but one approach is to store the settings required for the calculation as fields in some class (perhaps split your calculation off into its own class). Then, when the GUI button is pressed, the configuration is taken from the GUI, parsed, and copied to the calculation object before the calculation is performed.

This automatically gives you a few advantages:

- Since the configuration is now stored privately instead of in the GUI, GUI changes no longer affect the configuration of a running calculation -- unless you specifically want them to. You have full control.
- Input validation (e.g. checking if numbers are in range, etc.) can be handled by the calculation object. This has a lot of good consequences, most notably your calculation can now rely on stated invariants and always assume that the configured settings are in valid ranges. Also you can initiate calculations through means *other* than your GUI and still have validation.
- By separating your calculation code and configuration from the main application, you can now do all sorts of other things if you want, e.g. have multiple calculations running simultaneously on multiple threads, or whatever.

You may not want to do all of those things, but the point is you automatically get the ability to do them just by decoupling your business logic from your GUI.

Example:

```
class Calculation {

   final int input1;
   final int input2;

   Calculation (int input1, int input2) {
      if (input1 < 0 || input2 < 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inputs can't be negative."); // for example
      this.input1 = input1;
      this.input2 = input2;
   }

   void begin () {
      ...
   }

}
```

Then when your GUI button is pressed:

```
int input1 = ...; // get value from gui
int input2 = ...; // get value from gui
calculation = new Calculation(input1, input2);
calculation.begin();
// now the actual settings are preserved in 'calculation' regardless of gui changes.
```

Of course there are many ways to organize that (and the GUI button example above leaves much to be desired), e.g. you want ways to get periodic updates, etc., but it can all be done easily in that framework.

Also you don't *have* to have a separate instance of `Calculation` per calculation; you could use setters and such too, and do things like:

```
class Calculation {

   final int input1;
   final int input2;
   boolean running;

   Calculation (int input1, int input2) {
       setInput1(input1);
       setInput2(input2);
   }

   void setInput1 (int input1) {
       if (running)
           throw new IllegalStateException("Inputs can't be changed while calculation running.");
       if (input1 < 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input 1 can't be negative.");
       this.input1 = input1;
   }

   void setInput2 (int input2) {
       if (running)
           throw new IllegalStateException("Inputs can't be changed while calculation running.");
       if (input2 < 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input 2 can't be negative.");
       this.input2 = input2;
   }

   void begin () {
       if (running)
           throw new IllegalStateException("Calculation is already running.");
       running = true;
       ...
   }

}
```